# Making vector from frequency values in a table in R

Tags: r, vector, frequency

I have a vector of characters

```
helloWorld <- c("H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ",
                "W", "o", "r", "l", "d", "!")
```

I make a table of character frequency from it

```
frequency = table(helloWorld)
```

which gives :

```
> frequency
helloWorld
  ! d e H l o r W 
1 1 1 1 1 3 2 1 1
```

Now I want to make a vector whose value will be :

```
[1]  1 1 1 1 1 3 2 1 1
```

I mean I just want to make a vector `v` with the frequency values. How can I possibly do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can strip all of the table's attributes with `as.vector()`

```
as.vector(table(helloWorld))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 1 1
```

Alternatively (and about twice as fast), convert `helloWorld` to factor and use `tabulate()`

```
tabulate(factor(helloWorld))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 1 1
```